# Exclude a child with the navigation bar in React App

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <TopNavigationBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact strict component={Home} />
            <Route path="/signin" exact strict component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/register" exact strict component={Register} />
            <Route path="/main-page" exact strict component={MainPage} />
            <Route
              path="/create-event-process"
              exact
              strict
              component={CreateStation}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see from the App.js that I have in my react app, the pages will show the TopNavigationBar on every route. Is it possible to exclude the TopNavigationBar in the route "/"?

If it is not possible, is there a workaround? I want the "/" to be a blank page without anything for now.

Comment: Providing a complete answer to the problem would be too broad unless the poster narrows the scope by indicating what they have done already. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can narrow down the scope if I understand and know react and its packages more. I understand that there are a lot of ways of making things to work, won't it be better if there are many different solutions posted here all pointing to one question? I think it can help those who looks for a different kind of solutions.

Comment: It will be great if you can remove your -1 so that newbies like me will be helped by this 'broad" question.

Comment: This question is a duplicate... I understand that you are new, that's why I left a comment. If the question was made less broad I would flag it as a duplicate of either reacting to window.location or reacting to a React-Router route. In it's current form this is not useful for anyone but you, and it won't even be useful to you after today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in all kinds of ways, and depending on which router package this is, the approaches can vary a lot.

EDIT: 
It sounds like you need a solution like this

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Routes = withRouter(({location}) => (
  <div>
    {location.pathname !== "/" && <TopNavigationBar />}
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact strict component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signin" exact strict component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/register" exact strict component={Register} />
      <Route path="/main-page" exact strict component={MainPage} />
      <Route
        path="/create-event-process"
        exact
        strict
        component={CreateStation}
      />
    </Switch>
  </div>
));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and I am using react router. I don't see where I can put your piece of code to my code.

Comment: replace `<TopNavigationBar />` with `{location.pathname !== "/" && <TopNavigationBar />}`

Comment: I need to use window.location.pathname in order to make it works. Thank you

Comment: `location` is an object on `window`, it should be available simply as `location` - Is this a client app? Also which browser are you using?

Comment: `Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals` is the error message I get if I don't include `window`. Yes, it is a client app and I am using google chrome

Comment: Ahh eslint is pissed about the use of a global. Fair enough. Sounds like you're all set then!

Comment: Few minutes ago, I realized that using your solution is not a complete fix to my application. If I redirect to other pages from the `home`, those pages will not have the `TopNavigationBar` because the class App is rendered only once . I didn't know the existence of `location.pathname` until you posted your kind solution. Using your solution in my `TopNavigationBar` component js file, I keep track of the location and renders the nav bar in all pages except the home.

Comment: I see, in that case the `TopNavigationBar` needs to be passed `location` data as props. The way to do this is by using [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) - that will cause props to change and fix this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184541/discussion-between-james-and-calvert).